# Not able to reference local WSDL file when using PEX

Tags: python, python-3.x, pex

I have a question about pex  build. So we have this project structure and we are trying to build a pex file off of it.  It has a WSDL file which needs to be referenced in the code. No matter what I do, when I run the pex  file, it throws an exception: File Not Found . Does anyone have any idea how to fix it? I am fairly new to Python.

Below is the folder structure -

```
Main_Folder
  Util
    util1.py
      main.py
        WebService.xml
```

I tried this:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), 'WebService.xml')
url = urllib.parse.urljoin('file:', urllib.request.pathname2url(os.path.abspath(path)))
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope I ended up just unzipping the pex file and then use ```os.path.abspath``` to reference the WebService.xml file. It was much easier than spending more time to just reference the file.

Comment: Alright I've got this figured out and verified a solution works. I'm going to write up an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. As the error indicates, the path is not set correctly.

`os.path.abspath(__file__)` -> Gives you the absolute path of the file. If I run this code from a file named main.py I get the following output.

`C:\Users\User1\Desktop\main.py`

Example of os.path.join

```
# Path 
path = "/home"

# Join various path components  
print(os.path.join(path, "User/Public/", "Documents", ""))
```

Outputs

`/home/User/Public/Documents/`-> As you can see it joins the directories.

So you should now be able to see the problem you have. You path variable will hold something like this 
`C:\Users\User1\Desktop\main.py\WebService.xml`

So just change it to this  `path = os.path.abspath('WebService.xml')

You can read more about the os module [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/)

Comment: Thanks, I did do that way and it worked when I ran the main.py file directly. Hwoever, if I package the whole thing with pex it is throwing error. Saying it cant find the Webservice.xml because the absolute path is different.

Comment: I think the problem is since the xml file is zipped inside the pex file it wont let me reference that file. So when I generated the pex from the above directory, it includes all the files. When I am running the pex, it is getting the xml file path as "/users/aks/somefolder_pex_location/webservice.xml". This is where it fails. I am not sure what to do

Comment: **'I think the problem is since the xml file is zipped inside the pex file it wont let me reference that file'**   -> this is not true, it should be able to reference it. You may need to alter the values when running on your system and when generating a pex. Since .xml file is in the same directory as the main.py file, can you try setting the `path = 'WebService.xml'` when generating it and see what that does

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you need to do three things to be able to utilize static file resources within a PEX deployment package:

1. Make sure you initially build the PEX package with the `--not-zip-safe` option,
2. Forcibly install the `setuptools` pip package when initially building your PEX package, and
3. Utilize the [pkg_resources module](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) from setuptools to determine the right path to access your resources.

So in order to build your PEX package, you'll need a requirements.txt file that includes at least this line:

```
setuptools==49.2.0  # or whatever version, really, as long as some version is present
```

Then build the PEX file with something like this:

```sh
# first build the pex file with whatever pip requirements are needed
pex -r requirements.txt -e 'main:main' -o mypexfile.zip --not-zip-safe

# then add your files to it
zip mypexfile.zip Util/util1.py main.py WebService.xml

# finally, rename the extension (not strictly necessary)
mv mypexfile.zip mypexfile.pex
```

Finally, inside your `main.py` file, you'll need code like this to access the resource file:

```py
import os
import pkg_resources


def main():
    path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, "WebService.xml")
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print("file exists")
```

That call to `pkg_resources.resource_filename` basically is a way of looking up the ephemeral/relative path to where the file actually lives. If you print out the value of `path` you'll see it will look funny and unpredictable. For example, in my case it ended up resolving to this value:

> `/root/.pex/code/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709/WebService.xml`

But whatever that value actually is, the point is that the result of that call to `pkg_resources.resource_filename` will give you the correct path, which should allow you to freely access your resource file.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with your solution. I posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457013/how-to-add-properties-file-inside-a-pex-package). Mind taking a look?

Basically `pkg_resources.resource_filename` returns an actual path, but the file does not exist, I cannot open it.