# How to add properties file inside a pex package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, pkg-config, python-pex

I have this project:

```
project_folder/
    main.py
    setup.py
    requirements.text
    properties.ini
```

I build my `pex` file with this command: `pex . -r requirements.txt -c main.py -o mypex.pex`

**Q:** How do I add properties.ini into my final pex package? My python script cannot work without the properties.

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62956372/8524301), by adding the properties file with the `zip` command:

```
pex . -r requirements.txt -c main.py -o mypex.pex  # build the package
zip mypex.pex properties.ini  # add properties file, like suggested in the answer linked above
```

When I run with `python3 mypex.pex`, the line `pkg_resources.resource_filename` gives me an actual path:

```
/home/ubuntu/.pex/unzipped_pexes/884d0e35e7ba50e4dd0867ffd91d3d4fd273263c/properties.ini
```

but if I `open(path, 'r')` it, it gives me a `FileNotFoundError`. I can confirm the file does not exist because I tried to `cat` it.

That's what the beginning of main.py looks like:

```
properties_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, "properties.ini")
print(f'Properties path: {properties_path}') # prints an actual path (see above)

with open(properties_path, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read()) # throws an FileNotFoundError
```

My `setup.py` looks like this.

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='my-script',
    version='1.0',
    scripts=['main.py']
)
```

This method looks more like a hack than an official solution; what is the proper way of adding properties files (or any configuration file) to a pex package? Perhaps it has something to do with `setup.py`?